# java loop that replaces the previous number with new number

Tags: java, loops

I'm new to learning java and I am in the process of creating a fruit machine.

I want the slot machine numbers to spin through random numbers before displaying the actual result creating a spinning effect.

For this I think I need to create a loop of random numbers where each new number replaces the previous number e.g. if the first random number generated was "5" and the next was "7", the "7" would replace the "5" when it is displayed. I have no idea how and can't find an answer through research on the internet.

Comment: try to post short and relevant code.

Comment: Could you please explain what the problem is? `num1`, `num2` and `num3` seem to answer your question

Comment: There isn't a problem with my program but I want a loop that creates a certain amount of random numbers and I want each new number created to replacing the old number. Sorry if my explanation wasn't very good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a loop that generates n random numbers:

```
int num = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     num = Random.nextInt(9);
     doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Okay this is good but i need each new generated random number to replace the previous random number. So say the first number generated is "2" and the next is "5"; the 5 will replace the 2.

Comment: It does. Each random number is stored in variable num, and once you generate it, you can display it or do anything else that you want.